# How to start e2e tests after creating a new aurelia project

Tags: aurelia

So  I created a new project with aurelia-cli and selected protractor for e2e testing, I expected to have a command similar to `au karma` for running e2e tests but there is none.

How do I run the e2e test?

Comment: This blog may be helpful: http://mobilemancer.com/2017/01/05/aurelia-spa-unit-testing-and-e2e-testing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not quite work as expected, the nps trick does not work for a aurelia-cli project, probably works for webpacker.

Endedup using a combination of this post http://mobilemancer.com/2017/01/05/aurelia-spa-unit-testing-and-e2e-testing/ and the skeleton app here https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript-aspnetcore/src/skeleton

My config and task file are here https://gist.github.com/alexandru-calinoiu/8bf0a5e97f05311e388fe333f6b83b75

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I guess there is no command to run the e2e tests (as you can check here: https://github.com/aurelia/cli/tree/81b029191f4752fecdaf0192bb03c7cd0bc87d8f/lib/resources/tasks)

However, the CLI generated projects provide a lot of different `nps` scripts. One of it contains starting the e2e tests. However, `nps` itself is not a dev dependency in the CLI projects. A fast way to run e2e tests is the following:

On the CLI, change to your project and run:

```
npm install -D nps
```

This adds `nps` as a dev dependency and makes all scripts from `package-scripts.js` available (if you have installed `nps` globally, skip this step).

Then, you can run the e2e tests via:

```
npm start -- e2e
```

Or, if you have installed `nps` globally (or at least, it is available in your PATH), you can also run

```
nps e2e
```